# Python/Pandas DataFrame 1st line issue with datetime.timedelta

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

**REVISED:**
After looking, it seems my first problem is in the the creation of the dataframe using the for loop -df.append method.

Using a print statement to see the "Lines to be appended" section below, I then  assign the variables to dict pointers and the append the dict to what started as a blank dataframe.

The first line/append seems to change the type for that first entry on the last column.

```
  while read line
    if xx is not None and yy is not None and xx < yy:
       zz=yy-xx
       print (yy, xx, zz)
       parms['datein'] = xx
       parms['dateout'] = yy
       parms['time'] = zz
       df = df.append(parms,ignore_index=True)
       yy=None
       xx=None
```

At this point the dataframe **has the one odd entry in the first row and last column**.

Here:

```
                datein             dateout            time
0  2013-11-01 06:10:00 2013-11-01 12:06:00  21360000000000
1  2013-11-01 12:51:00 2013-11-01 14:53:00         2:02:00
2  2013-11-04 06:02:00 2013-11-04 14:04:00         8:02:00
3  2013-11-05 05:56:00 2013-11-05 12:11:00         6:15:00
```

So this is now a dataframe.append question.

Trying to sum datetime.timedeltas in a column is giving an error of :

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'long' and 'datetime.timedelta'
```

Displaying the dataframe itself shows an issue with the first line that doesn't appear in the lines appended to the dataframe.

Lines to be appended:

```
(datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 1, 12, 6), datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 1, 6, 10),datetime.timedelta(0, 21360))
(datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 1, 14, 53), datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 1, 12, 51),datetime.timedelta(0, 7320))
(datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 4, 14, 4), datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 4, 6, 2),datetime.timedelta(0, 28920))
(datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 5, 12, 11), datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 5, 5, 56),datetime.timedelta(0, 22500))
(datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 5, 14, 42), datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 5, 12, 38),datetime.timedelta(0, 7440))
```

Creating the dataframe with for loops from a dat file into dict using:

```
parms = dict.fromkeys(keys)
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=keys)
df = df.append(parms,ignore_index=True)
```

DataFrame output:

```
                           time
dateout                            
2013-11-01 12:06:00  21360000000000
2013-11-01 14:53:00         2:02:00
2013-11-04 14:04:00         8:02:00
2013-11-05 12:11:00         6:15:00
2013-11-05 14:42:00         2:04:00
```

Im using 
    df.groupby(df.index.date).sum()
But it seems the 1st line in the frame is throwing it off.
Any ideas as to why that first line showing up with the odd "long" reference?

**Revised 2**

Dat file:

```
IN    11/01/2013        14:32
OUT   11/01/2013        18:32
IN    11/01/2013        18:58
OUT   11/01/2013        20:57
IN    11/04/2013        14:33
OUT   11/04/2013        18:30
IN    11/04/2013        18:57
OUT   11/04/2013        23:01
IN    11/05/2013        14:29
OUT   11/05/2013        18:31
IN    11/05/2013        18:58
OUT   11/05/2013        23:01
IN    11/06/2013        14:30
OUT   11/06/2013        18:31
IN    11/06/2013        18:57
OUT   11/06/2013        23:00
IN    11/07/2013        14:30
OUT   11/07/2013        18:31
```

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import struct
from datetime import datetime 
keys = ['datein','dateout','time']
parms = dict.fromkeys(keys)
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=keys)
dat = open(datfile,'r')
for line in dat.readlines():

    opt, date, mgr, tim = line[:3], line[6:16], line[18:22], line[24:29]
    f = datetime.combine(datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y'),datetime.strptime(tim, '%H:%M').time())
    if opt == 'IN ' and f > datetime(2013, 11, 1) and f < datetime(2013, 12, 1):
        xx = f

    if opt == 'OUT' and f > datetime(2013, 11, 1) and f < datetime(2013, 12, 1):
        yy = f 

    if xx is not None and yy is not None and xx < yy:
        zz=yy-xx
        print (yy, xx, zz)   ## <-- Check lines before appending dataframe, output below
        parms['datein'] = xx
        parms['dateout'] = yy
        parms['time'] = zz
        df = df.append(parms,ignore_index=True)

        if len(df.index) == 1:
            print df.dtypes   ## <---- This shows 'time' as timedelta64

        if len(df.index) == 2:
            print df.dtypes   ## after next line appended 'time shows 'object' and first line loses type.
        yy=None   ## <-- reset before next loop
        xx=None   ## <-- reset before next loop

print dg.dtypes
print dg
```

Return from line print prior to append to df:

```
(datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 4, 14, 4), datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 4, 6, 2),datetime.timedelta(0, 28920))
(datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 5, 12, 11), datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 5, 5, 56), datetime.timedelta(0, 22500))
(datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 5, 14, 42), datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 5, 12, 38), datetime.timedelta(0, 7440))
(datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 6, 12, 7), datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 6, 5, 49), datetime.timedelta(0, 22680))
(datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 6, 14, 37), datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 6, 12, 24), datetime.timedelta(0, 7980))
(datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 7, 14, 7), datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 7, 6, 8), datetime.timedelta(0, 28740))
(datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 8, 11, 58), datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 8, 5, 53), datetime.timedelta(0, 21900))
(datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 8, 14, 10), datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 8, 12, 21), datetime.timedelta(0, 6540))
(datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 11, 12, 16), datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 11, 6, 6), datetime.timedelta(0, 22200))
(datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 11, 14, 31), datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 11, 12, 49), datetime.timedelta(0, 6120))
```

And the dtypes:

```
datein     datetime64[ns]
dateout    datetime64[ns]
time               object
dtype: object
```

And the dataframe showing the off 1st row:

```
                datein             dateout            time
0  2013-11-01 06:10:00 2013-11-01 12:06:00  21360000000000
1  2013-11-01 12:51:00 2013-11-01 14:53:00         2:02:00
2  2013-11-04 06:02:00 2013-11-04 14:04:00         8:02:00
3  2013-11-05 05:56:00 2013-11-05 12:11:00         6:15:00
4  2013-11-05 12:38:00 2013-11-05 14:42:00         2:04:00
5  2013-11-06 05:49:00 2013-11-06 12:07:00         6:18:00
6  2013-11-06 12:24:00 2013-11-06 14:37:00         2:13:00
7  2013-11-07 06:08:00 2013-11-07 14:07:00         7:59:00
8  2013-11-08 05:53:00 2013-11-08 11:58:00         6:05:00
9  2013-11-08 12:21:00 2013-11-08 14:10:00         1:49:00
10 2013-11-11 06:06:00 2013-11-11 12:16:00         6:10:00
11 2013-11-11 12:49:00 2013-11-11 14:31:00         1:42:00
12 2013-11-12 06:04:00 2013-11-12 12:24:00         6:20:00
13 2013-11-12 12:40:00 2013-11-12 12:59:00         0:19:00
14 2013-11-13 06:04:00 2013-11-13 12:19:00         6:15:00
15 2013-11-13 12:42:00 2013-11-13 14:35:00         1:53:00
16 2013-11-14 06:05:00 2013-11-14 12:22:00         6:17:00
```

Comment: pls make an example that is easily reproducible, e.g. can be cut and pasted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [a bug](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/5695). It can be seen below, in a much shorter example than in original question.

Setup:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
parms = {'d':  datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 5, 5, 56), 't':datetime.timedelta(0, 22500)}
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=list('dt'))
df = df.append(parms, ignore_index=True)
```

Erroneous code:

```
>>> df.append(parms, ignore_index=True)
                    d               t
0 2013-11-05 05:56:00  22500000000000
1 2013-11-05 05:56:00         6:15:00
```

Comment: Got around this by encapsulating the dict 'parms' in a spawned dataframe per loop and append the single row df to the major dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

This is using pandas 0.13 (0.13rc1 is out now). Timedelta support is only minimal in prior versions.

```
In [23]: df
Out[23]: 
                date1               date2       td
0 2013-11-01 12:06:00 2013-11-01 06:10:00 05:56:00
1 2013-11-01 14:53:00 2013-11-01 12:51:00 02:02:00
2 2013-11-04 14:04:00 2013-11-04 06:02:00 08:02:00
3 2013-11-05 12:11:00 2013-11-05 05:56:00 06:15:00
4 2013-11-05 14:42:00 2013-11-05 12:38:00 02:04:00

[5 rows x 3 columns]

In [24]: df2 = df.set_index('date1')

In [25]: df2
Out[25]: 
                                  date2       td
date1                                           
2013-11-01 12:06:00 2013-11-01 06:10:00 05:56:00
2013-11-01 14:53:00 2013-11-01 12:51:00 02:02:00
2013-11-04 14:04:00 2013-11-04 06:02:00 08:02:00
2013-11-05 12:11:00 2013-11-05 05:56:00 06:15:00
2013-11-05 14:42:00 2013-11-05 12:38:00 02:04:00

[5 rows x 2 columns]

In [26]: pd.to_timedelta(df2.groupby(df2.index.date)['td'].sum())
Out[26]: 
2013-11-01   07:58:00
2013-11-04   08:02:00
2013-11-05   08:19:00
Name: td, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Even this is not fully support (as I had to 'convert' the output back to timedeltas), this is currently an open issue with groupby and will be fixed for 0.14, see here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/5724

Comment: The issue actually seems to be from df.append(). The first row/last column is not following the timedelta type the appending data is listed as. Only after the first row being appended to the blank dataframe does the format work.

Comment: could be a bug; its not clear how to reproduce your example. if you fix it will be easier to tell.

Comment: @Jeff added a much shorter example as a cw answer. not sure if it's a bug

Comment: This is a bug, noted here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/5695. Merge/join/concat does not handle timedelta properly ATM.